# Chrome: Change order of buttons in the Camera permission popup

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, popup

Currently, the permission popup shown in my Chrome browser looks like below:

[image]

How can we change the order of the Block and Allow buttons?

I can see both the versions of the popup on the internet but don't know how to achieve them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser level popup and there is currently no way to personalize that popup. Also, every browser implements this differently, so even if you were to raise a feature request in Chrome for this, you might as well do it in all browsers. I doubt it is that big of a deal though.